# Changing 1 row in a dataframe from numeric to factor

Tags: r, numbers

I have this row in a data frame that is numeric, but I was trying to train a model for RF, and it seems to have factors (i believe) so was looking to either convert the row to factor or change the 0 & 1 to clarification text: 1 == 'gen' & 2 == 'nongen'.

I tried rbind but when combined, it changed it back to a number.

Thanks,
Tom

data example:

```
13     0
14     0
15     0
16     0
17     1
18     0
19     0
20     1
21     0
22     0
23     0
24     0
25     0
```

Comment: you can try `factor(df$col, labels = c('gen', 'nongen'))`

Comment: nice! worked well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign `labels` to `factor`

```
df$new_col <- factor(df$col, labels = c('gen', 'nongen'))
```

Or using `ifelse` :

```
df$new_col <- factor(ifelse(df$col == 0, 'gen', 'nongen'))
```